# Error font render in Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit?

Tags: 64-bit, fonts

I have copied all font on Windows 7 into Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and it error to render like the picture I post below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the problem exists for only the newly copied fonts, then it is a permission issue. Make sure the current user has the permission to "read" those fonts.